# Improving the below oracle query to be more effective

Tags: oracle

I am a new learner to the oracle world of sql queries but still how I need to bring the data from two tables for which I have fetched the query , now please advise is the below query is correct or still I can make it more efficient , any suggestions to improve it are welcome , Here below is the my query

Comment: HOw would we know what "correct"  is? How do you know it is not "efficient?"  What indexes do you have on the table?  Did you run an explain plan?  This question is too broad.  Can't really help without more details. Sorry

Comment: What query? Looks like you removed it in an edit, leaving the question meaningless. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should not convert your date datatypes to character when doing the comparisons. This has two negative effects

1. You effectively "hide" the statistics on those columns, which means
   the optimizer may not make the best choice of execution plan
2. If you have indexes on the columns, you are preventing their use.

If your `CREATED_ON` and `MODIFIED_ON` columns do not store a time portion, then your predicates can be simply

```
BC.CREATED_ON = trunc(SYSDATE)
 OR 
BC.MODIFIED_ON = trunc(SYSDATE)
```

If your columns **`do`** include a time portion, then you should formulate your predicates as shown

```
BC.CREATED_ON >= trunc(sysdate) and BC.CREATED_ON < trunc(sysdate)+1
or
BC.MODIFIED_ON >= trunc(sysdate) and BC.MODIFIED_ON < trunc(sysdate)+1
```

What you are trying to do, is avoid having a function applied to the columns, `TO_CHAR()` in your question